# When I try to use <i> tag in wordpress text widget, It auto remove after save

Tags: html, wordpress, widget, wysiwyg

When I try to add in wordpress text widget and insert some html code with  tag. after save code save. then I open widget again. that  tag removed.

```
`<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg" <="" i=""> </i></td>
<td>
<p>Company name<br>
Address</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"> </i></td>
<td><a href="tel:+1123456789"> (+1) 123456789</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> </td>
<td><a href="mailto:info@company.com"> info@company.com</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>`
```

Comment: You need to use `Custom HTML` widget for that. It is core widget.

Comment: i know that. my question is why can't use `<i>` in WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: See this link about text widget and Custom HTML widget. https://make.wordpress.org/core/2017/08/01/fixes-to-text-widget-and-introduction-of-custom-html-widget-in-4-8-1/

Comment: `add_action( 'init', function () { 
 global $allowedtags;
 $allowedtags['iframe'] = array(
  'src'    => array(),
  'height' => array(),
  'width'  => array(),
 );
    }); `

adding this code we can allow iframe.right? i want to add <i> to this. but it's not working.